# jquery autocomplete combobox get current input value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox

Is it possible to get current input value which user typed?

Problem is if combobox didn't last focus it is possible on clicking enter to submit form and I need to validate what user wrote even he isn't choose in dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just grab the `val()` of the search field's `<input>` element.

In the below example, we used `keyup` as the event to check if user pressed Enter key, and use that as the trigger to do what you want: grab the current contents of the search field.

If the field has been emptied, then you can use some other trigger to grab the contents of that field (remember, it is just a normal `<input>` tag) and perhaps store it into a hidden input field for safe keeping. Then, when you are ready, read the value you stored in that hidden input field the same way that we read the non-hidden input field in the example below.

Field to read: `<input id="tags">`

Method to read it: `strSrxField = $("#tags").val();`

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZF47s/)</kbd>

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

**jQuery/javascript:**

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});

$('#tags').keyup(function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        var srx = $('#tags').val(); //in this fn, you could also use $(this).val()
        alert('You entered: ' + srx);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code works great. But I need to take value from autocomlete combobox. and .val() .text() doesn't seem working. Actually they do but I cant get what user typed.

Comment: Please post some of your code so that we can create an example that you can use right away.